# What is the meaning of aggregate in Limits and continuity?

Tags: limits, definition

While defining limits, we define it as
Let f:S --> R be a function, 'a' be a limit point of aggregate S....
What does the word aggregate indicate in this context? Can someone please explain it in detail

Comment: It might mean set $S$. Post the complete definition.

Comment: Definition:Let f:S --> R be a function, 'a' be a limit point of aggregate S and l belongs to R(real number set). then the function f tends to limit l as x tends to a if for each (epsilon)>0 there exists (delta)>0

Comment: Aggregate is a synonym for set. Why, what else do you think it might mean?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Aggregate.html) you go. Which basically means sets.